boxplot in python while using filter on column
I am trying to make boxplot showing revolutions per mile for few of the car brands but cant make it work neither using matplotlib or seaborn.
data looks like this:

uru =pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':cars[(cars['Manufacturer']=='Audi') | (cars['Manufacturer']=='Suzuki') | (cars['Manufacturer']=='Toyota')], 'Rev.per.mile' : cars['Rev.per.mile']})
sns.boxplot(data=uru,x='Manufacturer',y='Rev.per.mile')

please advise

I've used a similar-looking dataset to get the figure below.

Modified mpg dataset from seaborn:
  Manufacturer  Model_year  Weight  Cylinders   Mpg
0    Chevrolet          70    3504          8  18.0
1        Buick          70    3693          8  15.0
2     Plymouth          70    3436          8  18.0
3          Amc          70    3433          8  16.0
4         Ford          70    3449          8  17.0
...

Imports and load data:
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

#Load data and add a 'Manufacturer' column
cars = sns.load_dataset('mpg').assign(
    manufacturer=lambda df:df.name.str.split().str[0].str.capitalize()
).drop(columns=['name', 'origin', 'displacement', 'acceleration', 'horsepower'])
cars = cars[cars.columns[::-1]]
cars.columns = [col.capitalize() for col in cars.columns]
cars.head()

Filter the dataframe and plot:
#Filter data to required manufacturers, and "Mpg"
cars_filtered = cars.loc[
    cars['Manufacturer'].isin(['Amc', 'Plymouth']),
    ['Manufacturer', 'Mpg']
]

#Box plot
sns.boxplot(cars_filtered, x='Manufacturer', y='Mpg', saturation=0.5)

#Optionally overlay the raw data
sns.swarmplot(cars_filtered, x='Manufacturer', y='Mpg', color='tab:red', size=4)

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(2, 3)

